# CameraCharacteristics doesn't return all the available resolutions

Tags: android, android-camera2

I'm trying to use the maximum resolution when taking a picture using the new `camera2` API. First of all, I try to get the available resolutions using the following code:

Charac:

```
CameraCharacteristics characteristics = mManager.getCameraCharacteristics(mCameraId);
        StreamConfigurationMap streamMap =
                characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
        if (streamMap == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("StreamConfigurationMap is null. Should not happen.");
        }
 streamMap.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.*); // I replaced the star with all possible values
```

The issue is this returns the following list of resolutions : `[1280x960, 1088x1088, 640x480, 352x288, 176x144, 3264x1836, 3264x2448, 1280x720, 960x720, 720x480, 320x240, 1920x1080, 2400x1080, 1440x1080, 2576x1932, 3264x1468]` (biggest is 3264x2448)

However when using the stock camera app (Samsung A70) the picture resolution is surprisingly bigger, ie: `4032x3024`.

During investigation I tried to download many camera apps from the store to see what is the max resolution in there case, and all of them returned the same resolution as mine, ie: `3264x2448`.

My question is how can the **Stock Camera App** get a bigger resolution than the rest of us?

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the output of [StreamConfigurationMap#getHighResolutionOutputSizes()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/params/StreamConfigurationMap.html#getHighResolutionOutputSizes(int)) as well?

Some devices list their highest resolutions there, because they can't maintain >= 20-fps output rate guaranteed by the BURST_CAPTURE capability, which is required for all sizes on the normal size list if you want a FULL-level device.  As long as at least 8 MP is listed in normal sizes, the device is compliant with the BURST_CAPTURE rules and higher resolutions can be listed under getHighResolutionOutputSizes.